# How to get ip addresses list on LAN on an android device connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, jcifs

My android device is connected to wifi. There is a shared folder on the computer. 
For example, the file manager on my phone detects the following ip addresses:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OmT7.png)

The first address is my computer, and the second address is my laptop.

I can hardcode the address for example

```
String url = "smb://192.168.1.57/" + SHARED_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + FILE_NAME;
```

But how can I get a list of ip addresses to which I can connect to avoid hardcode addresses?

Comment: Which file manager app is that?

Comment: I don't know, it's default app on my xiaomi

Comment: I think it just tries to connect to all possible ips. You could do the same. If the android device has ip 192.168.1.12 then start a thread that in a loop tries to connect to the rest of the possible ips. 192.168.1.##.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about such a decision, is there really no more beautiful way?